# Can't connect to ASUS router RT-AC66U B1

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have Asus router RT-AC66U B1 and can't seem to connect to the device via ethernet cable, wifi connection seems to be disabled too. How I tried to connect via cable:

1. Via `http://router.asus.com/`
2. Nothing can be found on `192.168.1.0/24` (checked with `nmap`)
3. Asus Discovery tool showing nothing on Windows.

How I tried to fix the problem:

- Used Asus router rescue tool to upload latest firmware. That was successful! How is it possible given that the device is not visible on any IP in range `192.168.1.0/24`?
- Factory reset

After factory reset I'd expect to see again the default networks, but they are not visible, LED for wifi is also not blinking.

Is the device beyond rescue? I think the problem was caused by incorrect reset in the first place.

Output of `arp -a`:

```
Interface: 169.254.36.82 --- 0x5
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

This would be empty if the router was not connected.

The device was set to AP mode before the feral reset. After flashing the firmware through asus recovery tool (that is, when the status reaches 100%), the power LED does not blink, it's lighted as in normal operations. It appears like it's booted, but the wifi LED are not up, nor any connectivity to the device.

After plugging the router to the internet, I get internet on cable on a connected PC. Clearly router stays in AP mode, despite the resets.

Comment: think the problem was caused by incorrect reset in the first place.    ....  Purely a suggestion from experience and may not work:   Unplug the router from AC and leave for 24 hours unplugged.  Then reset it again and try. If not, replace the router.

Comment: Is the router second-hand or new?

Comment: @harrymc It's over 3 years old, not second-hand though. It worked fine until one person decided to reset it and I think the process did not go well.

Comment: I suggest to connect the computer via ethernet to the router and disconnect both from everything else. Boot the router and then the computer and test if you can now access it. The computer should not have a static IP.

Comment: I did exactly that and could not access router anywhere on 192.168.1.0/24. Weirdly, the firmware rescue updater was able to communicate.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski that indicates that the recovery firmware is still working fine. You could get a cheap USB-UART adapter, e.g. a FT232, and connect it to the routers internal UART pin header. You will then be able to view status messages on the serial console, e.g. with putty. It will give you a better idea of what exactly is preventing the routers normal operation than the status LEDs. Sidenote: had one RT-N66U which took around 30min to boot after the recovery process. NEVER powercycle it after a recovery! Always wait until it starts by itself! (Unless its still stuck after 2-3 hours)

Comment: @mashuptwice Many thanks, that seems to be the best way to debug this. Do you think [Waveshare USB to TTL 4-pin](https://www.waveshare.com/usb-to-4-pin-wire.htm) would do the trick? No previous experience, hence the question.

Comment: BTW, after flashing the firmware through asus recovery tool (that is, when the status reaches 100%), the power led does not blink. It appears like it's booted, but the wifi LED are not up, nor any connectivity to the device. After that I tried hard reset to factory defaults. Again, the power LED stops blinking almost immediately. In both cases I am giving the device an hour before touching the power button. It feels like something goes wrong in the boot cycle. On the flip side, after plugging the router to the internet, I get internet on cable on connected PC. Clearly router stays in AP mode.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Yes, that linked product would definitely work.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski As you are on the B1 hardware variant, you could also try the recovery method [mentioned here](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-AC66U_B1)

Comment: @mashuptwice I have followed your advise to use serial connection. It wasn't giving anything, only after I booted it in rescue mode I saw it can't start the OS image. I cleared the nvram and then uploaded new image (the update would fail without clearing the nvram), the device booted successfully. Likely the method you linked would work too (the web interface allows to clear nvram and update, the asus recovery tool does not clear nvram). I will be more than happy to accept this as the answer. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Wrote an answer. Can you confirm 115200 as baudrate? It was quite a while since I've done that and I've wrote the answer out of my memory.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Apart from that: I can recommend [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/) as advanced firmware on the router. It runs more stable than most of the manufacturers firmwares and allows for advanced configurations that are usually only possible on expensive enterprise devices. DNS based adblocking can also easily be implemented. I use DD-WRT for 8 years on various different devices and never had to even restart a router because it got slow or uptight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asus RT series routers have a UART interface on the inside, which gives you a serial console when connecting it to a computer. It allows you to get much more detailed error messages than the status LEDs provide.

[image: UART header]

You will need a UART-to-USB adapter, for example based on the FT232RL or similar.
**Note: The routers UART work at 3,3V or 5V. Do not use a RS232 serial cable, as it operates at 12V and WILL destroy the router!**

### Instructions

0. **Disconnect the routers power and leave it disconnected until part 5, to avoid shorting something out and damaging the hardware! You can not only damage your router, but also your computer if making a mistake, so be careful!**
1. Open the device to access it. Remove all four rubber feet and the screws underneath.
2. Connect your router and the UART adapter as following:

```
ROUTER       UART-USB-ADAPTER 
  GND   <--->     GND
  RX    <--->     TX
  TX    <--->     RX
```

**Do not to connect the VCC pin, as we need to power the router via it's own power supply.**

3. Connect the UART adapter to your PC via USB.
4. [use PuTTY to establish a serial connection](https://pbxbook.com/voip/sputty.html) between your router and your computer. Use a baudrate of 115200.
5. Connect your routers power supply and switch it on. You should now see the bootloaders output in PuTTY.

If you get garbled text as output, find the correct baudrate through trial and error or research. Most common baudrates are 9600, 38400 and 115200.

6. Continue to use the serial output to identify the root cause of the problem. In case of a damaged or wrong firmware image, the bootloader (IIRC U-Boot) will tell you something along the lines of "failed to load system image" or similar.  It not only works for bootloader status messages, but also helps to confirm being in the recovery mode, or (in case of a functional firmware) output linux kernel messages.

If everything is configured correctly and yet you are not receiving anything on the terminal, it might be that the router OS is botched. Should this be the case, follow the router's manual to start it in a recovery mode. For RT-AC66U (and 86U):

1. Power off the router
2. Press and hold the reset button
3. Power on the router
4. Wait for the power LED to start slowly blinking

The router is now booted in the recovery mode and should start printing to the terminal (it could be e.g. timemout error). Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to get the prompt.

New firmware can be uploaded with e.g. Tftpd32 / [Tftpd64](https://pjo2.github.io/tftpd64/).

Another option, while it the rescue mode, is going to 192.168.1.1. You might need to set static IP on your machine, e.g. 192.168.1.2, to get it working. For the RT-AC66U / 86U displays a rudimentary web server that allows clearing NVRAM and uploading the firmware.

**Clearing the NVRAM might be a necessary step for the firmware update to work**.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! I will only add that in case the OS is botched, the router needs to be booted in a recovery mode (in case of the mentioned device: on turned off router, press and hold reset, power on, release reset when power LED starts blinking), otherwise you might not get anything in the terminal. If booted in recovery mode, Asus routers provide option to clear NVRAM and upload new firmware from 192.168.1.1. Clearing NVRAM was necessary before new firmware could be applied successfully.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski feel free to edit my answer with additional information for your specific router model! Every little piece could help others in the future!

Comment: Done. Indeed comments are not best for stashing this information.